# .net Okta and AWS authentication

Tags: c#, .net

Trying authenticate via Okta to access AWS resource using c#/.net. Found this sdk for .net https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-dotnet. Following the examples but do not know how to procced to list all AWS resources. Any help will be appreciated it. (credentials are not real and part of the example)

```
    var client = new AuthenticationClient(new OktaClientConfiguration
{
    OktaDomain = "https://{{yourOktaDomain}}",
});
var authnOptions = new AuthenticateOptions()
{
    Username = $"darth.vader@imperial-senate.gov",
    Password = "D1sturB1ng!",
};

var authnResponse = await authClient.AuthenticateAsync(authnOptions);
```

Comment: okta-auth-dotnet is used for authentication purpose. if your able to successfully authenticate then it's job done.

Comment: you might want to check AWS SDK for .net.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cloudformation-apis-intro.html

Comment: Thank you that makes sense do you know something similar to https://pypi.org/project/aws-okta-keyman/ but in .net?

Comment: Yes that is my goal to be able to use AWS sdk for .net but I have to authenticate via Okta to gain access to AWS.

Comment: The question is not clear. are you not able to successfully authenticate via OKTA  or you are not able to list resources of AWS.

Comment: Sorry about that I am not able to authenticate via Okta using .net to access AWS.

Comment: What's the output of authnResponse? does it have any message, status code?

Comment: I am just curious why you are not using existing integrations between okta and AWS. The applications are already pre-configured in OKTA Application Gallery. you just need to create the application and setup the configuration from user interface.

Comment: Right but the goals is to talk to AWS using .net/c# to perform automation in services in aws. To access aws I need to authenticate in Okta then get temporary access keys to access the AWS environment. I hope that makes sense. I have done it with python but having issues using .net

Comment: Are you looking for something like this "Using temporary credentials with AWS" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

Comment: The mentioned article also mention how to achieve that with AWS SDK for .NET

Comment: Thank you for the information will read it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: [Install the NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell). It will install all the dependencies too.

```
install package 'Okta.Auth.Sdk.2.0.3'
```

The code you posted should work with one change (name of the variable). Since you copied the code directly from the GitHub site.

```
using Okta.Auth.Sdk;
using Okta.Sdk.Abstractions.Configuration;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new AuthenticationClient(new OktaClientConfiguration
        {
            OktaDomain = "https://{{yourOktaDomain}}",
        });
        var authnOptions = new AuthenticateOptions()
        {
            Username = $"darth.vader@imperial-senate.gov",
            Password = "D1sturB1ng!",
        };

        //Asynchronous programming with async and await
        //var authnResponse =  await client.AuthenticateAsync(authnOptions);

        //Synchromous Programming - use Result - which would wait until the task had completed.
        var authnResponse = client.AuthenticateAsync(authnOptions).Result;
    }
}
```

I did verify the code. and the `AuthenticationStatus` was `SUCCESS`
[image]

Comment: Can you share the full code please. What kind of application did you use console or windows form ?

Comment: @Charlie Edited to include Complete Code. It's a console app.